# How to organize sass files, so compass includes them in the right order

Tags: compass-sass, yeoman, gruntjs

I'm building a single page app using the most recent yeoman build 1.0.0beta3 and compass 0.12.2

When starting `compass:server` I get lots of errors, but during dev time all seems to be ok in my browser. `grunt build` then does not fail, but builds improper CSS output, so that the layout in the browser is borken. Maybe that's all my fault, caused by a misunderstanding.

What I have is a `main.sass` file with all my includes:

```
// compass
@import 'compass'
@import 'compass/reset'
@import 'compass/css3'
... and so on

//custom includes in the right order
@import 'base/dimensions'
@import 'base/colors'
@import 'base/layout'
```

The file `base/dimensions` now defines:

```
// height of the footer
$footer-height: 50px
```

And (later) in `base/layout` I make use of that:

```
.content-bg
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)
  bottom: $footer-height
  ... and more
```

When starting the grunt and compass server now, I get the following error:

```
Running "compass:server" (compass) task
directory .tmp/styles/ 
  create .tmp/styles/avendor_font-awesome.css 
  create .tmp/styles/base_colors.css 
  create .tmp/styles/base_dimensions.css 
  error app/styles/base_layout.sass (Line 23: Undefined variable: "$footer-height".)
```

And lots of similar errors. (The footer height is indeed ok during dev time.)

I do not know how to solve that problem, and I do not know either if this causes the improper CSS after a build run. But when I build by issuing `grunt` I see the same errors in the console.

I should mention, I made some changes to Gruntfile.js, so that .sass files are loaded from subdirectories of /styles also:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: yeomanConfig,
    watch: {
        coffee: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.coffee'],
            tasks: ['coffee:dist']
        },
        coffeeTest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.coffee'],
            tasks: ['coffee:test']
        },
        compass: {
            **files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,**/}*.{scss,sass}'],**
            tasks: ['compass']
        },
        livereload: {
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                **'{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,**/}*.css',**
                '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,webp}'
            ],
            tasks: ['livereload']
        }
    },
```

Can anyone enlighten me?

Regards
Felix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For everyone facing the same problem: The naming of the files does the trick. Every file that is to be included in you main.css like so:

```
@include 'base/colors'
```

has to be named:

```
_colors.sass
```

instead of:

```
colors.sass
```

in the `base` directory in that case. What I did as well, was renaming `main.css` to `main.css.sass`

Now everything works correctly and I learned another thing the hard way.

Comment: This, however, has nothing to do with grunt or compass itself. That is just how SASS operates: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials

Comment: Codekit compiles 'un-underscored' SCSS without a problem and so does Compass from the CLI. Using grunt was the first time I've encountered this file-naming rule.

Comment: Thanks worked for. I don't know the reason behind this but this is the correct answer