# Order of importing compass/reset for Compass SCSS/SASS

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

In several examples (i.e. [Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/334-compass-css-sprites), [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605261/how-to-organize-sass-files-so-compass-includes-them-in-the-right-order), etc), I see "compass" being imported before "compass/reset" like so:

```
@import "compass";
@import "compass/reset";
```

Could someone explain to me why reset shouldn't come first? Or does the reset order not matter with respect to the base compass import?

```
@import "compass/reset";
@import "compass";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of Compass, it does not matter what order you do your imports because it is just a collection of mixins, functions, and variables.  Compass does not emit any styles unless you tell it to.

This may or may not be the case with other libraries, so make sure you always read the documentation.

Comment: Ah, understood. Thanks! Although, technically, when/how does the `global-reset` mixin get "called" from the Compass Reset Utilities ( http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/reset/utilities/#mixin-global-reset )? It seems to be appearing magically in my stylesheets (FWIW: I'm integrating Compass with a Rails 4 app)